# In the anime continuity, is there any parallel to Lulu's mistake with the King of Ginko's castle?

Tags: yuri-kuma-arashi

In episode 8, we learn that Yuriika was rescued, as an "unwanted bear", by someone who is only referred to with male pronouns.

[image: Yuriika's saviour]

This person visually reminded me of Ginko's mother in the *Yuri Kuma Arashi* manga, which, compared to the anime, approaches the plot and characters differently. (See the right panel.) In the manga, Yuriika also has a significant relationship to Ginko's mother. They first meet at the school, after Ginko's mother has become engaged to Yuriika's brother, and they later become lovers.

[image: Ginko's mother]

In the manga, Lulu speaks of Ginko living in a castle with a "King" and "Queen". The "King" is revealed to be Ginko's mother, rather than her father. We learn that Lulu was mistaken because someone referred to Ginko's mother with male pronouns — 彼 (*kare*), I believe — at some point. Lulu had this misunderstanding because Ginko's mother is named Kale, after [the Greek goddess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kale_(mythology)), which is pronounced similar to 彼 in Japanese.

Is there any parallel to this revelation of the "King's" actual gender in the continuity of the YKA anime? [One wiki](http://voiceacting.wikia.com/wiki/Yurikuma_Arashi#Minor_Cast) lists a woman as the voice actor for "Him", but that's not much to go upon.

Comment: given one of the themes of Yuri kuma it would be a (delightful) surprise if the "King" and the Queen are both women.